# Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting the below error on my code,

```
Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\go.php on line 15
```

Code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access
    allowed');
}

class Go extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('string');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if (!$this->uri->segment(1)) {
            redirect(base_url());
        } else {
            $url_code = $this->uri->segment(1);
            $this->load->model('Urls_model');
            $query = $this->Urls_model->fetch_url($url_code);
            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $url_address = $row->url_address;
                }
                redirect(prep_url($url_address));
            } else {
                $page_data = array(
                    'success_fail' => NULL,
                    'encoded_url'  => FALSE,
                );
                $this->load->view('common/header');
                $this->load->view('nav/top_nav');
                $this->load->view('create/create', $page_data);
                $this->load->view('common/footer');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That means "$this->Urls_model->fetch_url($url_code)" returns a boolean (maybe false because of an error or something?). Check the documentation of this method and read about the return value.

Answer (score 2):

@ahmed is correct that db code belongs in the model but the problem you're having is most likely from a db error.

Besides fixing the problem, the workaround is this.

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
```

should be changed to

```
if ($query && $query->num_rows() == 1) {
```

I would put an else in there to dump the $this-db->error() to the error_log so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: Is num_rows a function off the class? You can also use it without () right?

Comment: It's a function in codeignitor https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=num_rows#CI_DB_result::num_rows

Answer (score 0):

You should call the 'num_rows()' inside the Model, not the Controller, for this function is used often after the get() method:

```
//Model function:
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = Array();
if($query->num_rows()){
    //Work with data:
    foreach($query->result_array() AS $row){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}

return $data;
```

I suppose if you want to use the num_rows inside the controller, you should return the query AS a result like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data = [];
    $this->db->where('', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get('');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    $query->free_result();
    return $data;
```

First of all check that values come from database. if values come from table then put greater than 0 . if your value exist then query run forword. i thank this is help for you

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by buggy Active Records in CI that adds an extra WHERE clause causing ambiguous column names and similar.
Try to get the actual query with `$this->db->last_query();` and it will be instantly clear why **$query** is not an object.